# Where is this value in my configuration coming from?

Tags: git, git-config

When I use `git config --list` to check the value of `core.autocrlf` in `--system`, `--global`, and `--local` this is what I get:

```
$ git config --system --list | grep autocrlf
core.autocrlf=true
$ git config --global --list | grep autocrlf
core.autocrlf=true
$ git config --local --list | grep autocrlf
```

Which is fine.

But when I do it for everything (without the `--system`, `--global`, or `--local`), I get something odd:

```
$ git config --list | grep autocrlf
core.autocrlf=false
core.autocrlf=true
core.autocrlf=true
```

Where does that first `false` value come from, if it's not in my  `--system`, `--global`, or `--local`?

I am using the version of git that comes with SourceTree for Windows.

Comment: check .gitattributes maybe ?

Answer (score 0):

As you found out the configuration can be found under 3 location on your machine.

Sourcetree also has its own git version which you can use. 
if you use it and not the system git you will have another .gitconfig file.

This is where your values are coming from.

In windows you will find inside:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Atlassian\SourceTree\SourceTree.exe.config
```

Its not the usual git config, its an XML file which sourceTree reads the values from.

For example here is an entry from this file:

```
<setting name="DiffWhiteSpaceIgnored" serializeAs="String">
    <value>False</value>
</setting>
```

You can set it here:

[image]

Comment: Do the values of this XML file trump the values in the other configuration files?

Comment: Yep. you can defined properties to be used in sourcetree only.

Comment: Is it possible to modify this value through sourcetree?  I can't find any option for that under Tools/Options/Git.

Comment: updated answer to show you where to set it. If it helped you please be kind to accept this answer. Thank you.

Comment: It turns out that that's not it.  I set it to ignore whitespace, and I still am getting "core.autocrlf=false" from somewhere.