# git: where is my configuration information coming from?

Tags: git, macos, version-control

I have two conflicting config definitions in my git setup.

```
$ git config  --list|grep diff.tool
diff.tool=p4merge
diff.tool=extDiff
```

How can I tell where each of these definitions are being set on my MacOS system?

related windows question here: [Where is this value in my configuration coming from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34136453/where-is-this-value-in-my-configuration-coming-from)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet will show the three potential places where the configuration can be set.

```
$ for i in local global system; do echo $i:;git config  --$i --list|grep diff.tool;done
local:
global:
diff.tool=p4merge
diff.tool=extDiff
system:
fatal: unable to read config file '/usr/local/etc/gitconfig': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal. You should be at your User home by default. Run `ls -a` to see the hidden file `.gitconfig`, which will have user level configurations. In each repository run the same command to find the `.git` folder. Change directory into it (`cd .git`), and open the `config` file inside and make sure there are no configurations there.

You could probably run `open <insertfileName> -a textedit` to open the file in a basic text editor if you don't like command line text editors.